# CSS for specific text on Confluence

Tags: css, confluence

I am wondering if there is a way to use custom css for some specific text on my confluence page (not using embedded HTML).

Comment: Specific how? Can you show the HTML code of the text?

Comment: Specific means some text that should differ from all the other. The problem is that I can't use HTML on that page.

Comment: Well, what *defines* the specific text? You can't wrap some tags around it? Then it might be impossible to do

Comment: Yeap.. I can't use any HTML there... I was searching for a way to achieve that using some macros...

Answer (score 7):

Sorry this is an old question, but for the sake of people who search for an answer to this question: you can use span or div macros and use the custom css to apply whatever style you want to their contents.

If necessary, you could create custom div and span classes to allow for multiple styles to be applied to selections of text.

EDIT: Here is an example of the wikimarkup you could use to do this

```
{div:class=customCss|style=float:left; margin-right:50px}
Custom text in a div
{div}
```

So you can either use the div class and apply a style in the custom css for the confluence space, or you can use an inline style for the div.

Comment: ha, yep. The wiki inline style is written basically just like css. The "custom css" you can apply to a whole space is also just like css for html, since the wikimarkup is just displaying html content when it's actually viewed

Comment: I'm a Macintosh developer. I spent the day documenting stuff on our internal Confluence instance. Out of the box the styles for custom colored, monospaced text look awful, so I was trying to figure out how to make it look good. It turned out to be more of a learning curve than I had expected, but my biggest stumbling block was they syntax for this. I'll get the exact format figured out tomorrow morning. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this ...

```
{composition-setup}import.css=/download/attachments/123456789/custom.css
{composition-setup}
```

That's if you've stored a `custom.css` file as an attachement. You'd obviously need to replace *123456789* with the actual attachment number.

You can also link CSS on an external site (with an absolute URL), but if you have any automatic URL formatting, that tends to mess it up everytime you change the document.

Comment: looks good... but I want to use css class on some text, should be something like : 

{text:class="MY_CLASS"}MY TEXT{text}

Comment: Not sure about adding ids/classes, sorry. Try the Atlassian forums http://forums.atlassian.com/ - Might get a bit more help there.

Comment: To get the {composition-setup} macro, you can install Customware's [Composition plugin](http://wiki.customware.net/repository/display/AtlassianPlugins/Composition+Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

I use a User Macro that renders the $body in HTML. Then I can put whatever HTML tags I want in the wiki page within the user macro tag.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way to reach what you want to reach, but there is some information missing (from you). What confluence allows is the following:

- If you have admin rights to the confluence wiki space, you could add there a custom style sheet that applies to all wiki pages. Else you could follow the answer of [Mus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642861/mus).
- Then you should analyse the wiki page in source form. So load a wiki page you want to style, and look at the source of that wiki page in your browser. Depending on your browser, this may be `CTRL-U` or something similar. Here in chrome, the page menu says `View page source`.
- Try to find the defining selector for your wiki text you want to style in some form. A reasonable hack could be:

  - Find a wiki style that is not used by others. I have experimented with `~subscript~`.
  - Find the HTML tags that are built by using that style. In my example, it was `<sub>subscript</sub>`.
  - Use your custom style sheet to style text of that style.
  - However, this may change the text where the style is used for its original sense :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom CSS in your Confluence page via the `div` and `span` macros.

In recent Confluence versions (4.0 and later), you can do this as follows:

1. Type `{div}` or `{span}`. On typing the closing brace <kbd>}</kbd>, auto-complete will convert the text to a macro.
2. Left-click on the frame of the macro and select the Edit button 
   [image]
3. Enter the custom CSS into the Style field and close the dialog
4. Enter your text into the macro frame. It will then have the style you specified.